# Force query to return all ranges even when there is no data

Tags: sql, t-sql, case

I have a query which calculates 3 sums and classifies then into ranges of payment late days.

However sometimes there are no data for some of the ranges, so query returns less then 3 rows.

How to force the query to always return 3 rows, even when there are no data for specific `DaysLate` range? In this case `Suma` and `Docs` shall contain zeros.

```
SELECT MIN(b.Range) Nazwa, SUM(b.Remaining) Suma, COUNT(*) Docs
FROM (
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN a.DaysLate BETWEEN 1 AND 14 THEN 'Late 1 to 14 days'
    WHEN a.DaysLate BETWEEN 15 AND 30 THEN 'Late 15 to 30 day'
    ELSE 'Late over 30 days'
END AS Range,
CASE
    WHEN a.DaysLate BETWEEN 1 AND 14 THEN 1
    WHEN a.DaysLate BETWEEN 15 AND 30 THEN 2
    ELSE 3
END AS Order,
Remaining, DaysLate
FROM (
    SELECT DATEDIFF(dd, PaymentDate, GETDATE()) DaysLate, (WN - MA) Remaining
    FROM dbo.MyData
    WHERE DATEDIFF(dd, PaymentDate, GETDATE()) > 0 AND KOD_ID = @KOD_ID
    ) a
) b
GROUP BY b.Order
ORDER BY b.Order ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `LEFT JOIN`, but you can also simplify the query using `APPLY`:

```
SELECT ranges.range, SUM(v.Remaining) as Suma,
       COUNT(*) as Docs
FROM (VALUES ('Late 1 to 14 days', 1),
             ('Late 15 to 30 day', 2),
             ('Late over 30 days', 3)
     ) ranges(range, ord) LEFT JOIN
     (dbo.MyData d CROSS APPLY
      (VALUES (DATEDIFF(day, d.PaymentDate, GETDATE()),
               WN - MA
              )
      ) v(DaysLate, Remaining) CROSS APPLY
      (VALUES (CASE WHEN v.DaysLate BETWEEN 1 AND 14
                    THEN 'Late 1 to 14 days'
                    WHEN v.DaysLate BETWEEN 15 AND 30
                    THEN 'Late 15 to 30 day'
                    ELSE 'Late over 30 days'
               END)
      ) v1(range)
     )
     ON v1.range = ranges.range                  
WHERE v.DaysLate > 0 AND
      KOD_ID = @KOD_ID
GROUP BY v.range, v.ord
ORDER BY v.ord;
```